# error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript

buenas noches.
tengo el siguiente problemas resulta que estoy haciendo un juego de memoria utilizando JavaScript
tengo un array de objetos los cuales tienen las propiedades nombre: 'nombre de la carta' e imagen: "ruta de la imagen".
hasta aquí todo bien. el problema es que me estoy creando una función que se llama tablero donde quiero visualizar el tablero donde estarán las imágenes y obviamente las imágenes.

pero me aparece el erro Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND y se ve en miniatura todas la imagenes adjunto mi codigo;

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {

    const cardArray = [
      {
        name: "itachi",
        img : "imagenes/itachi.png"
      },

      {
        name: "shisui",
        img : "imagenes/shisui.png"
      },

      {
        name: "susano",
        img: "imagenes/susano.png"
      }
      
    ]
      const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

      function tablero() {
        for(let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
          const carta = document.createElement('img');
          carta.setAttribute("src","imagenes/blank.png")
          carta.setAttribute("data-id", i)
          //carta.addEventListener('click', flipCard)
          grid.appendChild(carta)
        }
      }
      tablero();
  
});
```

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Memory Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h3>Score:<span id="result"></span></h3>

  <div class="grid">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez haciendolo de esta manera funcione

```
  function tablero() {
        for(let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
          const carta = document.createElement('img');
          carta.setAttribute("src")
          carta.src = "imagenes/blank.png"
          // si no funciona asi puede ser que le falta el / quedaria asi
          // carta.src = "/imagenes/blank.png"
          carta.setAttribute("data-id", i)
          //carta.addEventListener('click', flipCard)
          grid.appendChild(carta)
        }
      }
```